# Where does the phrase "It's just business" originate?

Tags: origin-unknown

I have been a bit of a movie buff lately, and I have noticed the same phrase in several movies I have been watching lately (with some minor variation):

> *"It's just [good] business"*

This has occurred in multiple movies, which to my knowledge are completely unrelated, such as "Lego Movie", "Monsters vs. Aliens", "Pirates of the Carribean: Dead Man's Chest"* and "Pirates of the Carribean: at World's End"*, as well of a few others.

So where does the phrase come from?

---

<sup>*these are related (clearly), they are just a repeat by the same character in two parts of the same series.</sup>

Comment: "It's just business" is an idiom of long standing and it's origin is likely impossible to nail down.  In a movie context, the idiom is likely to be invoked when an actor (likely the villain) is about to make a decision that is pragmatic, cynical, and perhaps a bit selfish, vs being kind or altruistic.  The implication is that the action being taken is a simple business decision, and speaker is (self-) justified in not being emotional.

Comment: As to where the phrase comes from, I doubt that you can find an "origin".  It's an obvious expression for a cynic, and one can likely find similar phrases in Shakespeare and the Bible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did the research, I found a man by the name of [Otto Berman](http://theamericanjewishgangster.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/berman-otto-abbadabba-1-8801-935-policy.html). He was an accountant for an organised crime syndicate in the 1930's. He is the man who is believed to have coined the phrase ["It's not personal, It's just business"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Berman)

---

<sup>Answer taken from a separate (now deleted) migration from Movies & TV - originally by [Kristen Adell Miller](http://stackexchange.com/users/7063461/kristen-adell-miller). Can be seen [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41906/24253) by those with the necessary rep.</sup>